# Rewrite O(N W) in terms of N

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, discrete-mathematics

I have this question that asks to rewrite the subset sum problem in terms of only N.

If unaware the problem is that given weights, each with cost 1 how would you find the optimal solution given a max weight to achieve.

So the O(NW) is the space and time costs, where space will be for the 2d matrix and in the use of dynamic programming. This problem is a special case of the knapsac problem.

I'm not sure how to approach this as I tried to think about it and only thing I thought of was find the sum of all weights and just have a general worst case scenario. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on [cs.se]

Answer (score 1):

If the weight is not bounded, and so the complexity must depend solely on N, there is at least an O (2<sup>N</sup>) approach, which is trying all possible subsets of N elements and computing their sums.

Comment: But what about the approach in dynamic programming, where the complexity is trying to be decreased. I understand since W is unbounded then 2^n will be the time, so how would this apply with the method mentioned. Unless there really isn't anything?

Comment: @capa_matrix: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity), knapsack problem is NP-complete unless you have some other restrictions. Still, you can reduce 2^n to 2^(n/2) or better (read the linked article for some pointers).

Comment: @capa_matrix If you have an algorithm that works for general subset sum instances and its runtime depends only on n, it has to be exponential in n, unless P = NP

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use exponential space rather than polynomial space, you can solve the problem in O(n 2^(n/2)) time and O(2^(n/2)) space if you split your set of n weights into two sets A and B of roughly equal size and compute the sum of weights for all the subsets of the two sets, and then hash all sums of subsets in A and hash W - x for all sums x of subsets of B, and if you get a collision between a subset of A and a subset of B in the hash table then you have found a subset that sums to W.

Comment: @NiklasB For polynomial space I was referring to the brute force approach of trying all 2^N subsets. That clearly only requires polynomial space.